# Intel CET more secure than AMD Shadow Stack?

Tags: intel, rop, amd, shadowstack

I'm trying to decide between AMD or Intel for a new build. I was reading about protection from ROP-attacks and it seems like Intel and AMD are handling this in different ways.

AMD Zen 3 and later processors support Shadow Stack protection.

Intel Generation 11 and later support Intel CET. This includes Shadow Stack protection and also Indirect Branch Trackning (IBT).

Could somebody enlighten me about the difference and if Intel is indeed more secure against ROP (return-oriented programming)-attacks?